Implementación de ChatBot en Whatsapp
estoy intentando implementar un Chatbot para que atienda consultas frecuentes de usuarios a un Whatsapp Business. Probé hacerlo desde:

Manychat
Tidio
Chatfuel
Twilio

En todos los casos luego de implementar los flujos, parece funcionar (dentro del dashboard de la plataforma), pero al intentar probar si funciona fuera del dashboard, no funciona y Meta me avisa que "Restringimos tu negocio" ( adjunto imagen). en el mismo mensaje indican posibles causas:
a)Automatizaciones en las que una máquina crea una gran cantidad de actividad rápidamente
b)Automatizaciones que imitan la actividad humana.
c)Automatizaciones que disminuyen la actividad humana auténtica.
La primera (a) la descarto, ya que en conversaciones de Meta dice 0 de 250, o sea que no alcanzo a realizar ninguna, efectivamente eso pasa. Las (b) y (c) son justamente lo que deseo hacer y aparentemente NO se puede hacer, pero veo miles de videos y artículos en los justamente hacen eso y al parecer se puede hacer..Alguien me puede indicar si estoy omitiendo algo o dame alguna ayuda o material para instruirme.?
Gracias de antemano.

Saludos !!
